# $\int \frac{(e^z)}{z-\pi i} dz$, if C is the ellipse |z - 2| + |z+2| = 6

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

$$\oint_{C} \frac{e^z}{z-\pi i}\ \mathrm dz$$
If $C$ is the ellipse $|z - 2| + |z+2| = 6$, how is it $0$? I can find the singular point in $2$ and $-2$.

Comment: The singularity of the integrand is at $z = i \pi$, which does not lie within that ellipse. Therefore the function is analytic inside and on $C$, and the integral is $0$ by Cauchy's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Graph of contour and pole at $z=i\pi$**

[image: Integral is zero]

Perhaps this visual representation can help you intuitively [understand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem?wprov=sfla1) why

$$\oint_{C} \frac{e^z}{z-\pi i}\ \mathrm dz=0$$
Where $C$ is the ellipse $|z - 2| + |z+2| = 6$

Answer (score 0):

First, consider the set $S=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-2|+|z+2|<2\sqrt{13}\}$. This set can be shown to be simply connected.

Let $z\in C$

$\Rightarrow z\in\mathbb{C}$

Suppose $z-\pi i=0$

$\Rightarrow z=\pi i\Rightarrow |z-2|+|z+2|=|\pi i-2|+|\pi i+2|=2\sqrt{\pi^{2}+4}>2\sqrt{9+4}=2\sqrt{13}\Rightarrow z\notin C$

Thus by the contrapositive, $z\in C\Rightarrow z-\pi i\neq 0$

$\Rightarrow z-\pi i\neq0$

Thus, $\frac{e^z}{z-\pi i}$ is holomorphic on $S$.

Let $z$ be in the curve.

$\Rightarrow |z-2|+|z+2|=6=2\sqrt{9}<2\sqrt{13}$

$\Rightarrow z\in S$

Thus, the curve is inside $S$, and as $\frac{e^z}{z-\pi i}$ is holomorphic on $S$, so $\oint_C {\frac{e^z}{z-\pi i}}\, {dz}=0$